# Does incognito kills count as silent too?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

I am playing Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood Multiplayer for a while now, and i just got 31 lvl, and the reward for this level is Kill Streak - Streak Bonus +750 but it says i need to make 5 SILENT kills in a row.

So my question is, do this kills have to be SILENT (need to act for a second in high profile to get rid of incognito) or it can also be INCOGNITO kill?

Comment: Note that they're looking for silent _or higher_, not strictly silent.

Comment: Well, that was my question. It says "Silent kill streak bonus. 
This bonus is applied once you have killed five targets silently (you will see the Silent score).". There is no word about incognito. Both, ingame and in wikia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An incognito kill does count as a silent kill, so even if you get 5 incognitos in a row you should still get the killstreak. The way it works is that if you have silent *or* higher, you get a certain "silent bonus" (200 points) score when you get the kill. That's what counts it as a silent kill. If you got an incognito kill, you get the "silent bonus" as part of the "incognito bonus" (300 points) so it still counts.

Also, [here](http://www.toptiertactics.com/2011/04/assassins-creed-brotherhood-multiplayer-perks-streaks-part-4/) is a reference that says:

- Streak Bonus +300: Awarded for killing three suckers while Silent (or Incognito), this bonus doubles the value of your kills if you can make them stealthily. In general, I recommend this Kill Streak for cautious, patient play. It’s easily doable and can add thousands of points to your score every game if played right.
- Streak Bonus +750: Murder five people stealthily and you’ll be awarded 750 bonus points! Though this Kill Streak offers the greatest per-kill bonus, it’s also exceedingly hard to accomplish. In Wanted, Assassinate, and Alliance, odds are you will be taken out before filling five body bags. In Manhunt, Chest Capture, and Escort, you will rarely have the opportunity to remain Incognito while also being effective. Stick with the  +250 or +300 bonuses instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) That clears everything up. But in BH its 200 and 300 points for silent and incognito :P But that doesnt matter, i still get the point. Thank you